# SPACY vs NLTK word tokenize benchmarking

Tags: python, nltk, benchmarking, spacy, tokenize

[My code][1]

import nltk import spacy nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm",disable = [ 'parser', 'ner','tok2vec', 'tagger', 'attribute_ruler', 'lemmatizer']) nlp.max_length = 4532554

BIGDATA = open("/Users/harikaranharithas/Downloads/data/en/en.txt",'r')
BIGDATA_R = BIGDATA.read()

Nw = %timeit -o nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(BIGDATA_R[0:1000000])
OUT - 1.35 s ± 139 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
Sw = %timeit -o nlp(BIGDATA_R[0:1000000])
OUT - 125 ms ± 3.72 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Big data is a text file consisting of several Wikipedia article(2B words)

My PC specs are:
MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019)
2,6 GHz 6-Core Intel Core i7
16 GB 2667 MHz DDR4
Intel UHD Graphics 630 1536 MB(+4GB radon 5500)

Isn't Spacy faster than NLTK what am I doing wrong. I have read in papers that spacy is somewhat 8 times fasted in word tokenization how to benchmark spacy and NLTK correctly?

Comment: Don't post pictures of text.  Copy/paste your code into a `code formatting` block.  Also, what's `en.txt`, a word list of some size?  And what Python implementation did you test on, running on what CPU?  Those details are missing from your [mcve].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Passing the documents to `nlp` might be doing more than just tokenizing.

Can you try to explicitly use only the tokenizer?

```
from spacy.lang.en import English
nlp = English()

# Create a Tokenizer with the default settings for English
# including punctuation rules and exceptions
tokenizer = nlp.tokenizer

tokenizer(BIGDATA_R[0:100000])
```